# AngularJs md-grid-tile behind another md-grid-tile

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to do a ng-show/hide of a `<md-grid-tile>` with another. Because the `<md-grid-list>` height is calculated before, during a 'hide' of a grid-tile I'm left with empty gaps. How can I put the grid-tile underneath the other grid-tile so that I'll have no gaps in my grid-list ?
Example:

```
<md-grid-list>
  <md-grid-tile>
    //content
  </md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile>
    //content to hide if condition
  </md-grid-tle>
  <md-grid-tile>
    //content to show if condition
 </md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile>
    //content
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

Comment: could you please share some code?

Comment: Why don't you filter tile instead of hiding content?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `ng-if` instead of using `ng-show/hide`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

A false value of `ng-if` will remove completely the `md-grid-tile` from the DOM. `ng-show` makes use of the `display` css property instead of being removed from the DOM.

Some examples of use where `falsyExpresion` represent a custom expression to be defined:

```
<md-grid-tile ng-if="falsyExpression">
//content
</md-grid-tile>

<md-grid-tile ng-if="false">
//content
</md-grid-tile>
```

Comment: It will remove it from DOM, but it will leave an empty space. The total height of <md-grid-list> is calculated at compile time. ng-if will not change this height.